# Getting changed values of a QTablewidget into a QStringList

Tags: c++, qt, onchange, qtablewidget

In my qt c++ application I want to get the changed values of a Qtablewidget into a qt stringList! I used the on_tableWidget_cellChanged() method for this! But I get all the values of the table widget into the qstringList

following is my code
**MainWIndow.h**

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

private slots:
    void on_pushButton_clicked();

    void on_tableWidget_cellChanged(int row, int column);


private:
    QStringList changedValues;
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

**MainWindow.cpp**

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    ui->tableWidget->setColumnCount(1);
    ui->tableWidget->setRowCount(5);
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
        ui->tableWidget->setItem(i,0,new QTableWidgetItem(QString::number(i)));
    }
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}



void MainWindow::on_tableWidget_cellChanged(int row, int column)
{
changedValues<<ui->tableWidget->item(row,column)->text();

}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    QString concat;
    for(int i=0;i<changedValues.size();i++){
        concat+=changedValues[i];
    }
    ui->label->setText(concat);

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**short answer:**

Change:

- `void on_tableWidget_cellChanged(int row, int column)`
- `void MainWindow::on_tableWidget_cellChanged(int row, int column)`

to:

- `void on_tableWidget_itemChanged(int row, int column)`
- `void MainWindow::on_tableWidget_itemChanged(int row, int column)`

**Explanation:**

QTableWidget can set `QTableWidgetItem` with `setItem()`, or widgets through `setCellWidget()`, for each of them there are the signals `itemChanged` and `cellChanged`, respectively.

In your case you have `QTableWidgetItem` so you must use the signal `itemChanged`.

Comment: Thanx man how to make relevant changes to my code? I dont understand

Comment: You just have to change the name of the functions, for example in your .h you have `on_tableWidget_cellChanged(int row, int column)` change it to`on_tableWidget_itemChanged(int row, int column)`, similarly in the .cpp change `MainWindow::on_tableWidget_cellChanged(int row, int column)` to `MainWindow::on_tableWidget_itemChanged(int row, int column)`.